# How to communicate between functions with observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have function that callPhantom to render pdf, and i need to wait until all components load.
This is the function:

```
 this.http.get<[any]>("api/funds").subscribe(async funds => {
          for (let i = 0; i < funds.length; i++) {
            this.fund = funds[i];
            // here i need to wait until onChartLoad fired.
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 4000));
            await (<any>window).callPhantom({ id: this.fund.fileName });
          }
          await (<any>window).callPhantom();
        })
```

I have function 'onChartLoad' that fired after finish load chart.
I need to continue with loop to print all funds, 
So which type of observable appropriate to my case?

I try to use Subject, and cast it to promise:

```
await this.renderObservable.take(1).toPromise();
```

But then it wait just one time.

Add

```
 this.renderObservable = new Subject();
```

After that solve my problem, but i don't think is that the best way.

Comment: What is the sequence again? Load funds -> chart loads -> print each funds -> callPhantom with each funds?

Comment: For all fund, wait to load chart, then wait to render pdf, and then wait to load next fund.